# Highcharts - 5 Pie Charts, Each with 4-5 Drilldowns

Tags: highcharts

Is this possible, in a clean manner?  The 5 charts will all be displaying at once and the drilldown behavior will have to be ironed out, as to when one pie chart is clicked (drilled down into), the other ones' should drill down as well, given all the data is relative.

Has anyone gotten this deep into Highcharts and know if this is possible/how well it works speedwise?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? In general, there is not difference between drilldown for one chart and for 5 chart - always use the same way: use click event, and set new chart(or charts in your case). That's how drilldown example works.

Comment: Well in isolating one chart, I have the drill down working, but one issue is the page title not refreshing/updating once the chart begins back at level 0.

Comment: Do you have an example?